# Union of Date Column while also aggregate and joining

Tags: sql, left-join, union

I have two tables, one for actual invoices and one with budget numbers--both of them have a date column, the budget date column goes through the end of the year. My aggregate query only brings in sales & budget numbers through the most recent invoice date. How can I use UNION to have my output include future budget dates as well?

```
select
t1.invoice_date
,t1.sales_company_id
,t1.Sales
,t2.Budget
from 
(
  select 
             invoice_date
            ,sales_company_id
            ,sum(Sales)
  From Invoices
  group by
            invoice_date
            ,sales_org_id
) t1
            
left join  
(
   select 
            budget_date
            ,sales_company_id
            ,sum(Budget)
   from Budget
   group by 
            budget_date
            ,sales_company_id
) t2
  
on t1.invoice_date = t2.budget_date
and t1.sales_company_id = t2.sales_company_id
;
```

Comment: Try switching the order with budgets preceding invoices in join. Or use `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: Aside: See [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below updated MYSQL Query.

```html
SELECT
  invoice_date,
  sales_company_id,
  SUM(sales) AS Sales,
  SUM(Budget) AS Budget
FROM (
  SELECT 
    invoice_date,
    sales_company_id,
    SUM(sales) AS sales,
    0 AS Budget
  FROM Invoices
  GROUP BY invoice_date, sales_company_id
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT 
    budget_date,
    sales_company_id,
    0 AS sales,
    SUM(Budget) AS Budget
  FROM Budget
  LEFT JOIN Invoices ON Budget.budget_date = Invoices.invoice_date AND Budget.sales_company_id = Invoices.sales_company_id
  WHERE Budget.budget_date >= (
    SELECT MAX(invoice_date)
    FROM Invoices
  )
  GROUP BY budget_date, sales_company_id
) t
GROUP BY invoice_date, sales_company_id;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you Hidesh-- this helps but it removes the budget data from my invoice dates as well. I still would want that included. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I have updated my response query. kindly please review it again.

Comment: I'm now getting an ambiguous column name error on sales_company_id

Comment: I figured it out. Added some aliases to remove ambiguity and I also removed the following: LEFT JOIN Invoices ON Budget.budget_date = Invoices.invoice_date AND Budget.sales_company_id = Invoices.sales_company_id
  WHERE Budget.budget_date >= (
    SELECT MAX(invoice_date)
    FROM Invoices
  )